# How can I add a Google Map with Drupal?

Tags: html, drupal, drupal-6

I have a page that works fine pulling users and locations from a Drupal database ..

http://www.wpcreations.net/gmaptest/map.html

This is a working version. I know Drupal has a module that does the job and I am using parts of it. But for some reason if I use the map include it fails. But I can make an HTML page that does the same thing and works. Is there a way to put all the code from my HTML page in the site? Or, how can I force the map/markers to appear? I tried to use an iframe and that did not work.

Sorry, I'm new to Drupal. I'm using version 6.19 and can't go higher. Thanks for your time.

Comment: what is the input format that you are using on that node?

Comment: I tried just creating a new input format raw with no filters and then i did same with full html.

Comment: have you tried to enable php filter in the modules and use php filter as input format.

Comment: yes i tried that and still unable to figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a combination of 3 modules that will help you solve your task:

1. [**Location**](http://drupal.org/project/location) - enable: Location + User Locations
2. [**Views**](http://drupal.org/project/views) - enable: Views + Views UI
3. [**GMap Module**](http://drupal.org/project/gmap) - enable: GMap
4. [*Keys*](http://drupal.org/project/keys) - Optional

After you install the modules you have to configure them:

- Gmap - at least enter the **Google Maps API Key**
- Location - set the permissions and go to User settings and configure the new **User locations** options. After this users will be able to fill in fields regarding their location (City, Province, Street, Longitude&Latitude etc). You have many options here so for example you can provide a default country, you can make some fields mandatory, others optional etc.
- Keys - is an optional module but it's good to have when you want to manage multiple Keys. Scenario: you have a test version and a live version of your site so you'll need two Google Maps API Keys. Using this module will spare you changing the keys all the time.

Now to demonstrate the concept:

- add a new View -> View type: Users
- add a page view

  - Style: Gmap
  - Enter the page path
  - Fields: whatever fields you enabled for the users on the step for setting up location step

Go to the page view and if everything work you should see your users on a map.

You can get creative and, just like a page view, build different blocks and place them in different places on your site. Advantages is that you can place them pretty much anywhere you want.

Answer (score 0):

Use the drupal modules

http://drupal.org/project/gmaps